# Responsive on desktop but not mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive, viewport

I have searched the internet for quite a few hours now and cannot figure out why my site is responsive on the desktop but not on mobile (at least on my iphone X). On mobile, all of my elements except the gif at the top of the page are over to the left and half hidden outside the browser window (with no horizontal scroll bar btw). I have the viewport meta tag in there, which is the only solution I could find, but it did not do anything to my site's mobile view when I checked after adding it in. What else could the problem be? I am very much a beginner, so I am hoping this is just a dumb little mistake. Someone please help. I'm about to tear my hair out here!

You can visit the site here and resize to see how it should be, this is how it looks on mobile currently (not a full view btw, just a shot of the bottom sections of my site as you can see the problem most clearly from there):
[Mobile Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUGb2.jpg)

here is my code:

```
       <!doctype html>
<!-- This comment line needed for bootstrap to work on mobile devices -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Jasmine Thorson</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
</head> 
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="#work" class="nav">WORK</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="nav">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#skills" class="nav">SKILLS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" class="nav">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#top" id="logo"></a>
<div id="top"></div>
    <div id="box0">
    <img src="headergif_vert.gif" alt="myhero" class="hero">
    </div>
    <div id="work"> 
        <div id="box1">
        </div>
        <div id="box2">
        </div>
        <div id="box3">
        </div>
        <div id="box4">
        </div>
        <div id="box5">
        </div>
        <div id="box6">
        </div>
        <div id="box7">
        </div>
        <div id="box8">
        </div>
        <div id="box9">
        </div>
        <div id="box10">
    </div>
</div>
    <div id="about"></div>
    <img src="ABOUTGIF.gif" class="aboutgif" alt="aboutgif">
    <div id="aboutme">
    <h1 class="abouthead">I'm a young creative fresh out of college with lots of <mark class="pink">charisma.</mark></h1>
    <p class="para">I believe that good design can help people laugh, cry, stay informed, & understand each other better. Design, simply, is visual communication.</p>
    <p class="para">As a designer + photographer, it's my goal to capture the essence of my subject & express that essence in the most clear, consistent, & appropriate manner.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="skills"></div>
    <div class="w3-container">
        <table class="table1">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="ICONS_BRANDING.png"  alt="branding" class="icon1"></td>
                <td><img src="ICONS_INFOGRAPHICS.png"  alt="info" class="icon1"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img src="ICONS_DIGITAL.png"  alt="digital" class="icon1"></td>
                <td><img src="ICONS_SOCIAL.png"  alt="social" class="icon1"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <table class="table2">
            <tr>
                <td><img src="ICONS_BRANDING.png"  alt="branding" class="icon2"></td>
                <td><img src="ICONS_INFOGRAPHICS.png"  alt="info" class="icon2"></td>
                <td><img src="ICONS_DIGITAL.png"  alt="digital" class="icon2"></td>
                <td><img src="ICONS_SOCIAL.png"  alt="social" class="icon2"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>    
    </div>
    <div id="contact"></div>
    <div id="contactbox">
        <div class="col1"><h2>JASMINE THORSON</h2></div>
        <div class="col5"><h2>INFO</h2></div> 
        <div class="col1">Graphic Designer + Photographer</div>
        <div class="col2">Brooklyn, NY</div>
        <div class="col3">605 + 268 + 3245</div>
        <div class="col4">jnthorson@gmail.com</div>
        <div class="col5">Resume</div>
    </div>
    <footer>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/jasmine.thorson/"><img src="insta.png" id="insta" alt="gram" class="social"></a>

            <a href="https://www.behance.net/jnthorson"><img src="behance.png" id="behance" alt="be" class="social"></a>
    </footer>   
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
    @charset "UTF-8";

body {
    background-color: #DBD9D6;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
    color: #978B87;
}

p {
    font-family: Geneva;
    font-size: .75em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

h1{
    line-height: 1.25em;
}

h4{
    color: #D41773;
    column-span: all;
}

h5{
    color: #D41773;
    font-size: .65em;
}

#menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold";
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height: 10px;
    right: 0;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 4;

}

#menu li, #menu a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    opacity: .35;
    padding: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu li, #menu a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #D41773;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: color 0.3s linear;
}

#menu li, #menu a:active {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #D41773;

}

#logo {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px;
    width: 207px;
    height: 53px;
    background-image: url("logoheader.png");
    z-index: 4;
}

#logo:hover {
    background-image: url(logoheader.png);
    background-position: 0 -54.5px;

}

img.hero {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;     
}

#box0{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #DBD9D6;
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


#box1{
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(box1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#box2{
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(box2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#box3{
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(box3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#box4{
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(box4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#box5{
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(box5.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#box6{
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(box6.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#box7{
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(box7.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#box8{
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(box8.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#box9{
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(box9.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#box10{
    height: 60vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(box10.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

#aboutme {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 75%;
    width: 300px;
}

.abouthead{
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.para{
    font-size: .55em;
}

mark.pink{
    color: #D41773;
    background: none;
}

.aboutgif{
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px)  {
    .aboutgif{
        display: none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px)  {
    #aboutme{
        width: 200px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px)  {
    #aboutme{
        width: 250px;

    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px)  {
    #aboutme{
        width: 370px;

    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px)  {
    .abouthead{
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px)  {
    .abouthead{
        font-size: 2em;

    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px)  {
    .abouthead{
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px)  {
    .para{
        width: 200px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px)  {
    .para{
        font-size: .25em;
    }
}

.w3-container{
    background-color: #C5BBB6;
    margin-top: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.table1{
    width: 350px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px)  {
    .table1{
        display: none;
    }
}

.table2{
    width: 650px;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px)  {
    .table2{
        display: none;
    }
}

td{
    padding-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}

.icon1{
    width: 85px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.icon2{
    width: 110px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#contactbox{
    float: left;
    width: 85%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    column-count: 5;
    column-rule-width: 0px;
    font-size: .5em;
}

#contactheaders{
    column-span: all;
    display: inline;
}

.col1{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.col2{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.col3{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.col4{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

.col5{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

footer{
    position: fixed;
    display: inline;
    padding: 40px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10px;
    background: none;
    color: black;
    z-index: 5;
}

.photo{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10%;
    font-size: .6em;
    opacity: .25;
    color: black;
}

#insta{
    width: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 65px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

#behance{
    width: 25px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10%;
}

#behance.social, #insta.social {
    opacity: 0.25;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    transition: 0.3s linear;
}

#behance.social:hover, #insta.social:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

As I said before, I am a BEGINNER. Literally a beginner. We did not really learn this stuff in school, we were allowed to use Muse instead and I was afraid of how confusing coding looked so I am learning right now and I'm sorry if my code is just disgustingly awful, but I could really use some help! I ran both codes through validators and came out with minimal errors (which I fixed).

Comment: `<!-- This comment line needed for bootstrap to work on mobile devices -->` - says who? What would be probably more needed, is a proper doctype.

Comment: And valid HTML to begin with - having a navigation-UL inside HEAD is of course wrong. HEAD is meta data, BODY is content ...

Comment: Oh I think "all the elements are half off the page" is a bit misleading, I should say all of my "boxes" (the section that's inside div id="work") are half off left of page, everything below that section is, like, weirdly small and floating left, but not half off the screen.

Comment: @CBroe sorry doctype should be in there, didn't copy it accidentally

Comment: Why is your nav inside your head?

Comment: @ATomCalledStu because I am a dumb beginner coder. Thank you guys for pointing that out!

Comment: You have many mistakes which will lead to this problem.I recommend that you run your code through the [w3c validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: @MichaelMcQuade I did- I already corrected errors and warnings it gave me, which according to the validator were minimal. Can you give me specifics?

Comment: When I copy the code into the validator I see several problems, like the others pointed out you cannot place content within the head tag. The errors it shows can also be caused by the doctype, though, since it defaults to HTML 4.0.1. If you've corrected your code please edit your question.

Comment: Apart from the technical issues, you are making the typical designer mistake of valuing the "coolness" of tiny font sizes over readability btw. The body copy in your codepen is practically unreadable on desktop, if I don't want to crawl into my screen.

Comment: @CBroe Oh jeez, thanks for pointing that out. It does look fine on the site though? I'm not experiencing tiny text when I go to the actual site jasminethorson.com

Comment: Nah, same there - the calculated font size is shown as 8.8px in dev tools.

Comment: @CBroe ok cool, I will mess with that more. So, from what I'm gathering, my mobile view is crazy because my code has technical errors? According to the validator I fixed them– is there anything else you're seeing specifically that I need to fix?

Comment: The whole page is super-laggy in my browser. And I mean so extreme, that if I encountered it while surfing privately, I would probably close it after half a minute at most. Granted, not the most powerful computer I am sitting at right now, but serves me fine almost everywhere else on the internet. But this page almost refuses to obey to any kind of scroll command, reaction is delayed by several seconds. Probably the overuse of full-size parallax backgrounds. Sorry if this is a bit much, especially if you are a beginner, but this still needs some work.

Comment: @CBroe Ok, so I need to mess with my parallax boxes or find some other solution for that section. Noted! Anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one possible solution would be to center your entire page. Keep your HTML as it is, and add this CSS:

```
html,
body {
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This will tell your html and body to be centered. 
I hope this helps.